# How to reference column name instead of e.ColumnIndex in WinForm DataGridView event handlers?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

Some event handlers for the WinForm `DataGridView` have `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` as a parameter and a `ColumnIndex` as a property of that argument.

`ColumnIndex` is a number representing the column's ordinal #.

Is there a way to reference a column name from that argument instead of column index?

So instead of doing:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
```

I prefer something like:

```
if (e.ColumnName == "CustomerName")
```

because if a column changes its position, it will break the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure. It's of course not directly *in* the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs`, but it's easily obtainable. In your event handler:

```
DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
string columnName = dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
```

Comment: string columnName = dgv.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name; if you are using VB.NET instead of C#

Answer (score 6):

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == dgv.Columns["CustomerName"].Index )
{
    and so on....            
}
```

Comment: On my RadGridView I need the UniqueName="CustomerName" set

Answer (score 4):

The answers above works great but if you have to reference cell index a lot then I will just add private int members to the form, name them "idxMeaningfulColumnNameHere", then initialize these members in Form's constructor. I found it much easier this way.

```
idxMeaningfulColumnNameHere =
    this.YourDataGridViewNameHere.Columns["ColumnNameHere"].Index
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a custom method to be added to your DGV.

```
<Extension()>
Friend Function getColumnIndexByName(ByRef dgv As DataGridView, ByRef colName As String) As Integer
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dgv.Columns
        If column.Name = colName Then Return column.Index
    Next
    Try
        Throw New Exception("Column Name not Found")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(colName & ": " + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return -1
End Function
```

With that you can do something like:

```
If dgv1.getColumnIndexByName("SOME_COLUMN_NAME") = e.ColumnIndex Then Do_something()
```